# Clicking a javascript button with HtmlUnit

Tags: java, javascript, button, htmlunit

I'm trying to click a Html button using HTMLUnit.
Button code:

```
<input class="Submit" value="I Accept." type="submit" name="ButtonSubmit" id="button" onclick="/*some looong js code*/" tabindex="16">
```

My code

```
final HtmlSubmitInput baton = form.getInputByName("ButtonSubmit");
HtmlPage page2 = baton.click();
```

I tried using click(); method but it does not work.

also pressing enter key:

```
final HtmlTextInput textinput = form.getInputByName("SomeInput");
//filling input
HtmlPage page = textinput.type(KeyboardEvent.DOM_VK_ENTER);
```

I think problem is with the js code. It just does't run using HTMLUnit. (Filling the form manually, with browers, works fine.) Thanks for help.

Comment: What is the type for `form`?

Comment: HtmlForm form = page.getFirstByXPath("//form[@class='reg-form']");

Comment: and the page is HtmlPage

Comment: It is impossible to help if all you say is `it does not work` => So what happens? What is the output you get? What error/exception?

Comment: It dosn't return any error or exception. page2 returns html page, with fielld inputs, but it doesn't send a http reqest to server.

Answer (score 1):

make sure to enable JS in your code

webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will solve your problem, but there are two things I do differently to get around this (Javascript doesn't seem to click on elements):

- Use `form.getElementById("button")` instead of `getInputByName`
- Use `Thread.sleep` to wait (around 350 ms seems to be the magic number) for the effect to take place

Even with this, I still see non-determinstic test failures because the effects of the click sometimes just don't seem to happen.

Comment: I've tried the Element stuff but it does not change anything. JS still does't run. Sleep did't work ass well.

Comment: See my comment above. If your type of `form` is `HtmlPage`, this should actually work.